# Introduce CiviCRM in Italy

Tags: wordpress

who can I contact and how can I do to introduce CiviCRM in Italy?
Translating Documentation in Italian?
Thank you.
Marco

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by introducing CiviCRM in Italy?

Answer (score 3):

I can only give my experience in Hungary.

When I started contributing to CiviCRM first I translated the strings in Transifex. I took me a half year to translate nearly all strings.

Translation needed me firstly, beacuse we can use Civi UI translated. 
See the Italian pages:
https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm/language/it/

Later I translated some presentation and tried to spread words about CiviCRM on Hungarian forums, and sites where I can find interested guys.

Visit the Get Involved page: https://civicrm.org/get-involved

The whole documentation translation big chunk of work.

Answer (score 1):

I think an Italian translation exists - see all languages at: https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm/

To help click Help Translate CiviCRM